# JPA load child of child list

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

Using spring boot and hibernate, given I have a `UserEntity` with a child `TrailEntity` list:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "USER")
public class UserEntity {
  @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
  @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
  @JoinColumn(name="userID")
  private List<TrailEntity> trails = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

when I add a new `TrailEntity` and save, it works fine and `UserEntity.trails` contains the new `TrailEntity` objects.

```
userEntity.getTrails().add(trailEntity);
userService.save(userEntity);
```

However, there's another list in the child which gets saved but doesn't get loaded:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TRAIL")
public class TrailEntity {
  @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
  @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
  @JoinColumn(name="TrailID")
  private List<ImageEntity> images = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

when I do:

```
userEntity.getTrails(0).getImages().add(imageEntity);
userService.save(userEntity);
userEntity = userService.findByUsername(USERNAME);
```

`userEntity.getTrails(0).getImages().size()` is 0.

i.e. the `ImageEntity` objects linked to `TrailEntity` are saved but is there a way to load all the way down through the hierarchy in JPA (hibernate)?

Comment: can you show the transaction in which you are doing the save etc?

Comment: thanks for that, your comment reminded me to turn on sql logging and it showed ImageEntity being saved. The problem is actually it's not loading them, have changed question accordingly

Answer (score 0):

Turned out it was down to another entity in `ImageEntity`:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "IMAGE")
public class ImageEntity {
  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  @JoinColumn(name="BeaconID", nullable=false)
  private BeaconEntity beaconEntity;
}
```

but it was never used and was causing the associated `ImageEntity` objects not to be loaded from the database due to `nullable=false`.

Removing `nullable=false` (default is true) for `ImageEntity.beaconEntity` solved the problem